# set in collections allows duplicate values?

Tags: java

```
public class TestSet {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Set s = new LinkedHashSet();
    s.add("Windows");
    s.add("Mac");
    s.add("Mac");
    s.add("Unix");
    System.out.println(s); 
  }
}
```

as per the defination.. set should not allow duplicate values... when add method is trying to insert duplicate values... it should return false.... but why is this code giving output as [windows,mac,unix] instead of error??

Comment: Yes, the third call to `s.add("Mac")` will return false - but that doesn't *remove* it from the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set interface is like the mathematical abstraction of a set. No need to throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

`Set#add` returns `true` if this set did not already contain the specified element else `false`. It does not thorw `Exception` if value is duplicate.

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present
>   (optional operation). More formally, adds the specified element e to
>   this set if the set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ?
>   e2==null : e.equals(e2)). If this set already contains the element,
>   the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false. In combination
>   with the restriction on constructors, this ensures that sets never
>   contain duplicate elements.

[Find more on Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29)

```
boolean result = s.add("Mac"); // would be true
boolean result1 = s.add("Mac");// would be false
```

Comment: Subhrajyoti Majumder thank youn so much... now the concept is clear

Comment: best way to build your concept is read documentation :) 
mind it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can see the size of the set.It will omit any duplicates.This will print 3 in your case

```
System.out.println(s.size());
```